# Given an array of integers, find the subset sum closest to K

Tags: algorithm, subset, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

I know this is a knapsack problem where the weights and values are equal but I think I am making a mistake in my coding logic, since its taking too long to complete even for a problem where the number of elements in array (N) is 50 and the maximum sum required (M) 4500.

Just to clarify the question, we are given an array of N positive integers and a positive integer M. The array elements can be used only once.
We have to find a subset of this array (not necessarily contiguous) such that the sum is the closest to M but **doesn't exceed it**.

Here is my attempt using dynamic programming:

```
int M, N, price[100];
int memo[5000][100];

int dp(int left, int g)
{
    if (left < 0)
        return -10000000;

    if (g == N)
        return M - left;

    if (memo[left][g] != -1)
        return memo[left][g];

    int ans = -1;

    ans = max(ans, dp(left - price[g], g + 1));
    ans = max(ans, dp(left, g + 1));
    //cout<<g<<ln;
    return memo[left][g] = ans;
}

void solve()
{

    cin >> M >> N;

    forn(i, N)
    {
        cin >> price[i];
    }
    int score;
    memset(memo, -1, sizeof memo);
    score = dp(M, 0);
    //print_dp(M,0);

    if (score < 0)
        cout << "NO SOLUTION";
    else
        cout << score << ln;
}

int main(){
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

So is there any optimization possible in my code that could help bring me down the complexity because this isn't even the biggest test case, there is a test case with M = 10^9.
And also how do I track the actual subset incase of a solution since here I am just returning the final maximum possible sum.
Any guidance would be appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the next code ([ideone](https://ideone.com/uFXQ7W)).

For every price (`p`) it checks all cells of `memo` array and marks cell `j` if it possible to compose value `j` with `p` and some previous sum `j-p`. It also updates `jmax` - max possible sum and returns it as result. For data set `M=9 N=4 {2 3 5 11}` it gives `8` as possible sum `(<=9)` of array items.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int M, N, p;
int memo[5000];

int solve()
{

    cin >> M >> N;
    int i, j, jmax = 0;

    memset(memo, 0, sizeof(memo));
    memo[0] = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> p;
        for(j=M; j>=p; j--){
            if(memo[j-p]) {
               memo[j]=1;
               if(j>jmax)
                 jmax = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return jmax;
}

int main(){
    std::cout<<solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow this is a great answer ! But as I mentioned in the question that there are data sets of the size 10^9, and we essentially require an array of size 10^9 here and for some reason the compiler is throwing an  "error: size '4000000028' of array 'memo' exceeds maximum object size '2147483647'
int memo[1000000007]; "

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YUcWThEv
Here is the test case for reference

Comment: @Banana Bamboo For large M values and rather small N we can use dictionary (map) instead of array, so only existing sums will be stored.

Comment: To avoid scanning all values upto M, in large-M case build new map, adding p to every value in current map.

Comment: @BananaBamboo What is the origin of this big test case? Is it a coding challenge or something you've cooked up yourself? My program tells me that there are exact solutions that sum to 10^9 and the minimal such subset size is 1812. It's probably going to be easier therefore, to search for a maximally sized (188) subset of elements to exclude that sums to 9833203 which is full array sum minus 10^9. Did you solve this?

Comment: @BananaBamboo I wrote a simple-ish DP program that solved this big test test in 36.6s on my old 3.2 GHz Ivy Bridge Xeon, though it did require 20GB RAM. I found all 188 elements to exclude from the set to make the remainder sum to 10^9. There may be other solutions, but for mine, the largest excluded element is 101690.